# AWS ec2 and sending email from a Grails app

Tags: email, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to set up email service on an AWS EC2 instance? I'm talking about something simple like sending contact form contents from Grails app to the owner, not any sort of bulk or newsletter operations.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon imposes limits on how many emails a new EC2 account can send, even if you are just sending those emails to yourself.  To get this limit raised, fill out this form:

> https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

The form also has space for Elastic IP addresses to have whitelisted as well as rDNS values for improving your chances of getting the emails accepted by the receiving ISP.

You can either send email out from the instance directly (e.g., using SMTP to remote hosts or installing postfix to do the SMTP connections for you) or you can send the email through Amazon's SES:

> http://aws.amazon.com/ses/

Both Amazon themselves and ISPs receiving email from Amazon EC2 IP addresses are highly sensitive to spam like activity, so monitor your deliverability carefully and respond quickly when your email  or IP address gets flagged.